# How to fix a squeaky light switch

Tags: electrical, lubrication

I have a light switch that makes a loud high-pitched squeak when turned on or off. I'd like to apply some sort of lubricant to it so that it's not so loud, but I'm not certain as to what risks are involved given that it's electrical wiring.

Is there a safe lubricant that can be used on a light switch, or am I better off to just replace the switch altogether?

Answer (score 5):

It's a standard single-pole, single-throw switch?

[image: switch]

Just replace it. They cost $1 or so, and it's not worth the hassle to figure out what's wrong with the current one.

Comment: Agreed. Given how cheap most switches are, don't trust one that's acting up in any way.   They make much better switches in the $4 range.

Answer (score 0):

Right don't ever try to lubricate and electrical device. Most lubricants are conductive.

Comment: keyword being "most", there are some non-conductive lubricants designed for electronics, but from my research they appear to be more expensive than a replacement switch.

Comment: I thought about mentioning non-conductive lubricants, but I changed my mind. I have to assume that people who are asking these questions have a low skill set when it comes to electrical, and I believe it is my responsibility to judge if information I give them can become misinformation to the untrained. So If you refer to Article 110.11 Informational note #2. "Some cleaning and lubricating compounds can cause severe deterioration of many plastic material use for insulating and structural applications in equipment."

Comment: I use a spray dielectric grease for lubricating switches but on one of these I would just replace it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a new Lutron dimmer with the side slider. The toggle switch squeaks. I haven't tried it yet, but standard dielectric (spark plug boot) grease is non-conductive and would probably work just fine. Find it at auto parts or hardware stores.

Comment: I don't think this should have gotten a down vote I use dielectric spray grease all the time. Not much difference in the type for plug boots except it is thicker.+ should have read your answer before putting my comment.

Answer (score 0):

A 5oz can of CRC 2-26 lubricant costs $2.98 at Home Depot. You can lubricate 100's of switches with one can. Certainly much cheaper and easier than replacing the switch. For the price of 3 switches @ $1.00 each, this is much more cost effective.